# Package minted: \mint Command Not Working Inside tabularx Environment

Tags: tables, highlighting, tabularx, minted, inline

The question, [How to embed a minted environment inside a tabular environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112994/how-to-embed-a-minted-environment-inside-a-tabular-environment), addresses a similar issue, but I am using:

1. the `tabularx` package, and
2. the inline `\mint` command

Is there a workaround available for this?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{minted}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lrX}

Type & Meaning & Size \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3}

\mint{c++}|float| & single precision floating point  & 6 significant digits \\
            &               & Typically represented in 32 bits \\   

\mint{c++}|double| & double precision floating point  & 10 significant digits \\
            &               & Typically represented in 64 bits \\

\mint{c++}|long double| & extended precision floating point  & 10 significant digits \\
            &               & Typically represented in 96 or 128 bits \\        

\bottomrule                                                     

\end{tabularx}              

\end{document}
```

Comment: `tabularx` reads the table's contents as an argument, which limits the possibilities of including verbatim material. The package makes some adjustment in order to allow a restricted form of `\verb`, but doesn't cover other verbatim-like macros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two ways to get this to work.

## First method

**Edit:**  For this approach to work, you will need to use the patch for `\mint` that is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83558/error-caused-by-interaction-between-minted-footnotes-babel-and-double-quote/83573#83573).

Use `\savebox`.  Before the `tabularx`, define something like the following for each of the terms you need.

```
\newsavebox{\floatinabox}
\begin{lrbox}{\floatinabox}
\mint{c++}|float|
\end{lrbox}
```

Then, inside the `tabularx`, use something like `\usebox{\floatinabox}`.

The `lrbox` typesets its contents in a box, and saves the box for later use rather than inserting the box in the document.

This same approach can be used for inserting a `minted` environment, except that a `minipage` is required to allow linebreaks (see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41665/cant-i-put-a-list-inside-an-lrbox)).

```
\newsavebox{\mintedbox}
\begin{lrbox}{\mintedbox}
\begin{minipage}{3cm}
\begin{minted}{c++}
long double
\end{minted}
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}
```

## Second method

Use the Pygments highlighting from my `pythontex` package.  The `\pygment` command takes the same arguments as `\mint`, and usually works in these types of situations as long as `#` and `%` aren't involved.  I checked, and it does work in this case.

Comment: I've got two questions. One, why does the first method work? What makes the \mint command work normally inside an lrbox.
Two, could you please add to the answer, what one should do to get the minted environment working inside a tabularx cell?

Comment: @Chatterjee I've extended the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm getting a new error message now, saying

`Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item`

Comment: @Chatterjee I'm not sure what would cause that...I'd probably need to see the code. Maybe you could edit the question, or provide a link to the current version.

Comment: I've added the code!

Comment: Try using the patch for `\mint` [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83558/error-caused-by-interaction-between-minted-footnotes-babel-and-double-quote/83573#83573).  Just copy everything from the `\makeatletter` through the `\makeatother` (including both of those) into your preamble.  I was experimenting with using that patch when I answered the question, and hadn't realized that it seems to be needed.

Comment: @Chatterjee The answer is updated. The syntax highlighting part of `pythontex` is not a separate package because integrating the highlighting with code execution (`pythontex`'s main purpose) is considerably more efficient overall. For future reference, I recently began maintaining `minted`. I will be updating it with several patches from this site and features from `pythontex`, so in the relatively near future you should be able to do everything with an updated version of `minted`.

Comment: Sorry to bother you with this, but could you please take a look at this similar question I posted today, and provide any sort of suggestions?

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117077/using-minted-environment-in-user-defined-environment-minted-inside-minipage

Rather, would this be possible with `verbments`, since I see it is a bit better off compared to `minted`