# Minted inside tabular

Tags: tables, minted, code

I know this question has been asked before, but it didn't quite solve my issue. ([How to embed a minted environment inside a tabular environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112994/how-to-embed-a-minted-environment-inside-a-tabular-environment))

The described workaround (bringing `\end{minted}` to a single line) does work, however only if the code comes *second*. When I try to put the minted-section into the first column I get this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}, ]
```

I used this code:

```
\begin{tabular}{rp{0.5\textwidth}} 
\begin{minted}{c}
int main() {
  printf("hello, world");
  return 0;
}
\end{minted}
& testing
\end{tabular}
```

What can I do? Thank you

Comment: The first column is an `r` type one, so paragraphs are not allowed in it.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Stating @egreg's solution explicitly, try `\begin{tabular}{p{0.5\textwidth}r}`. Let us know if this resolves the issue :) Welcome!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you look at the linked question, you'll see that the `minted` environment appears in the *second* column, which is declared as `p` type.

You can't have an enumerated list or a `center` environment or anything that requires breaking lines in a column declared as `r`.

So just declare the first column as `p`. For instance

```
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5\textwidth} r}
\begin{minted}{c}
int main() {
  printf("hello, world");
  return 0;
}
\end{minted}
& testing
\end{tabular}
```

will work.

[image]

Of course the alignment will be wrong. You can remedy by adding a `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5\textwidth} r}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{minted}{c}
int main() {
  printf("hello, world");
  return 0;
}
\end{minted}
\end{minipage}
& testing
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Now if one has to use a minipage, then `c` would be valid, wouldn't it?  Also, in the first option, adding a background (`\begin{minted}[bgcolor=black]{c}`) gives weird results, so it seems minipage *is* required in any case.

Comment: @Michaël How to add a background is a new question, I guess.

Comment: Agreed, although I do know how to add a background, and I'd hope that a functioning solution to the current question wouldn't break this basic feature.  In any case, this little exchange may be helpful to anyone searching for tabular minted backgrounded environments!